# Is it too late to plant potatoes in Dorset, UK in Mid -september?

Tags: potatoes

Is it too late to plant potatoes in Dorset, UK now (Mid-September) ?

Comment: Can you tell us if you want to plant seed potatoes, fully grown potatoes or just the eyes? What variety?

Comment: This is on behalf of my wife but I think she said seed potatoes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way too late is the answer - potatoes aren't frost hardy for one thing. You've got two choices in the UK with potatoes - early crop or main crop. Earlies are chitted before planting in late March, maincrop are planted early to mid April - chitting for these is useful, but not as critical for early plantings. There is a way to grow them though, which is in a polytunnel, then you can plant now and with luck have your own potatoes for Christmas Day.

Answer (score 3):

Early potatoes will mature in about 90 days, or about three months. From now, that will be about december 15, if you can provide normal growing conditions, such as temperatures over 60 Fahrenheit, even at night. Later varieties may take up to 150 days or so, which would make them mature in mid February, in normal conditions. Lower temperature will only make the plants take longer.

Where you are, this isn't practical at all, and the capital you'd need would be more than the crop is worth, because potatoes perform best when planted in spring, and retain their quality well in storage. It's not worth the trouble, seriously. I'd wait for spring.